# Detecting color in video feed

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, emgucv, managed-c++

I know that this seems like a question that has been asked a million times, and it definitely helped, but I haven't been able to find anything that can help me with my specific problem. Overall, my project is centered about detecting a blinking LED that's blinking a Morse Code, and then translating that Morse Code. What I've done so far is I've thresholded an image so that only the LED will show up, everything else is black. The light from the LED is red. So what I want to do to start off is print out either a "0" or "1" depending on if the LED is on or off. However, I am not sure how to detect any color in an image. Here is the part of the code that I'm working on currently

```
if(frameFromCamera->InRange(new Bgr(0, 0, 200),new Bgr(0, 0, 255)) == 255){
        tbMorse->Text ="1";
    }
    else{
        tbMorse->Text = "0";
    }
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
BAOTFISInterface.cpp(1010): error C2664: 'Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth>    ^Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,unsigned short>::InRange(Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,unsigned short> ^,Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,unsigned short> ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr *' to 'Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth> ^'
          with
          [
              TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Gray,
              TDepth=unsigned char
          ]
          and
          [
              TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Gray,
              TDepth=unsigned short
          ]
          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
          Cannot convert an unmanaged type to a managed type
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using VS2010 so I have to use EMGU cv formatting to use the OpenCV library. This is all in Managed C++. I will take any pointers or suggestions that I can get.

Comment: `^` - no, this is not in C++. C++ types don't contain ^. And you certainly shouldn't use emgucv from C++. OpenCV is natively C++.

Comment: Removing the "new"'s didn't do anything. I thought this was managed C++? That's what my supervisor told me, anyways. @MSalters

Comment: I didn't even know "managed C++" was still supported by Microsoft. That was a failed idea. Despite its name, it certainly wasn't C++. IIRC, they had something like `gcnew`. But if this is a new project, ditch the managed stuff, emguCV and use plain C++.

Comment: Well the source code for this entire project was written in 2009, and I'm the first person to try to do any sort of updates to it since then. I'm using older versions of Emgu and OpenCV and Visual Studio too.